# Vite Build + React 18 - Blank Screen (empty console logs)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, vite

I'm working on a Vite/React app.  There's a CI process in place that runs the following and pushes the dist bundle to an S3 bucket.

```
vite build --mode production
```

I noticed recently that a commit I did caused the application to "white screen".  React is not rendering the "App" component (in main.tsx for instance):

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container!);
root.render(
    <React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <ProSidebarProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <App/>
                </BrowserRouter>
                ...
```

When looking at the blank page, opening up the console logs and I don't see any stack traces.  React dev tools clearly sees React running with a production build.  I've tried adding error boundaries to no luck.  I'm not sure how to debug which error is causing the component to not render.

I'm able to reproduce this locally.  If I run the build command above and then the following:

```
vite preview
```

I can see the white page on **localhost:4173**.  The odd thing is if I run the following command:

```
vite dev
```

I'm able to run the app perfectly fine on **localhost:5173**.

The dependencies from package.json

```
{
"react": "^18.2.0",
"vite": "^4.0.3",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
}
```

My Vite config:

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default ({mode}) => {
    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            react(),
        ],
        base: './',
        build: {
            target: 'esnext',
        },
    });
};
```

If in the above code (from main.tsx) I replace

`<App />`

with

`<h1>it works</h1>`

this renders perfectly fine on ports 4173 and 5173.  Issue is trying to find diagnostic information as to why the App component is not being rendered.

Comment: Is the app in a subdirectory on the S3 server? i.e. `https://....com/myapp`

Comment: I'm using Jenkins to push the dist to the S3 bucket behind the Cloudfront distribution.  There's no subdirectory, the root domain points to the S3 bucket directly.

Comment: if it is deployed, how about providing the URL?

Comment: It may be as simple as setting `index.html` as the default path for all requests if you have not done that on the S3 instance. It sounds like it could be a `react-router` issue too. Make sure you have set package.json `homepage` prop to the deployed URL, the `basepath` attribute on the `<BrowserRouter>` as described in deployment docs for `react-router`.

Comment: I see a login prompt - it is not blank. Open a different browser or open it in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by me using the **react-lazy-with-preload** package incorrectly.

If in a component I load the following lazy:

```
const Searchbar = lazy(() => import("../../components/Searchbar/Searchbar"));
```

And then I do this:

```
await Searchbar.preload();
```

This led to the blank page upon Vite build.  Correct usage:

```
Searchbar.preload();
```

Comment: How did you figure this out? I am facing the same kind of issue but I am not using the react-lazy-with-preload package.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any error on a console, like any dependencies are undefined,

Try this:

Add:

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
```

```js
    plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgrPlugin(), vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            process: "process/browser",
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib",
            util: 'util',
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
        },
    },
```

This in the `vite.config.ts` file and install all dependencies which are shown in that error message. Like if `blob-stream` shows an error add this in the alias in `vite.config.ts` and install `blob-stream`

```js
blobStream: "blob-stream",
```